# Is there a way to get the TID (thread id) in powershell foreach-object -parallel?

Tags: powershell, foreach-object

Just wondering if I could get like a $TID for thread id, just like a $PID or process id, with foreach-object -parallel in powershell 7 or pwsh (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#-powershell).  I can run this and see a bunch of threads with a TID column in sysinternals procexp (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), in the pwsh.exe properties, Threads tab.

```
 1..20 | foreach-object -Parallel { start-sleep (5*$_) } -ThrottleLimit 20
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? When I try to run your snippet I get an error: "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters"

Comment: @Dai Powershell 7 which is pwsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike for the *process* ID (`$PID`), there is *no* [automatic PowerShell variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) reflecting the *thread* ID (as of PowerShell 7.2).

If getting the *managed* (as opposed to the native) thread ID is sufficient, you can use .NET APIs ([`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)):

```sh
1..2 | % -Parallel { [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId }
```

To get the *native* thread ID you need *platform-specific* solutions via P/Invoke; e.g., for *Windows*, using the [`GetCurrentThreadId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentthreadid) WinAPI function:

```sh
# For Windows
Add-Type -Name WinApi -Namespace demo -MemberDefinition @'
  [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
  public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();
'@

1..2 | % -Parallel { [demo.WinApi]::GetCurrentThreadId() }
```